# How to intercept and process in a java constraint test violation (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed)

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

How to intercept and process in a java test constraint violation (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed). I have a database, there I set the constraint to delete the record. During the test, constraint is triggered and terminates the test. Accordingly, the test did not pass. How to make it so that when you throw out the message about the ban on deletion, the test passes

```
 try {
    new RowName.delete(new RowName.get(1));
    // constraint is triggered when deleting
} catch (Exception e) {
   ??????????
}
```

org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT] Abort due to constraint violation (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed)

Comment: You can't bypass such an error simply by setting a try/catch statement in code. The error is thrown in the database and reported to you by the code. You can't execute a sql statement if it violates a constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you ask for, but here we go:

```
try {
    new RowName.delete(new RowName.get(1));
    fail("It should not be possible to call .delete. DB should throw an exception since this is a violation of a constraint.");
} catch (org.sqlite.SQLiteException e) {
    // Just continue. We expect an SQLiteException since the test data has a 
    // constraint that forbids the .delete.
}
// Any other exception that is thrown will cause the test to fail which
// is what we want. The SQLiteException is expected since you forced it
// to happen. Other exceptions have to be examined and handled.
```

So if the .delete is not OK and therefore the DB throws an exception, your test will pass. But if the .delete goes through, something is wrong with your database or your test data, and then fail("...") will case your test case to fail.

Comment: Hello "Use e.g. e.printStackTrace() to figure out which exception is thrown." org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed)

Comment: @Yurii See updated code sample (including updated comments)